# Appium - Android Hybrid app

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I see console 'driver null' error after executing test script

**Script:**

```
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.4.0");
System.out.println("<<< Detects android device / emulator >>>");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","New1");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview","true");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
//capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "180");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "com.android.launcher");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sciit.mat");
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

**Console Error:**

```
<<< Detects android device / emulator >>>
<<< Utlizes remote webdriver >>>
Driver in App screen : null
FAILED: sampletestmethod
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ErrorCodes;Z)V
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<clinit>(AppiumDriver.java:46)
at com.sci.matapp.sampleScript1.TestScript1.sampletestmethod(TestScript1.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1064425: 521 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@6ea0c6: 508 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 131 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@899482: 746 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@d17bee: 551 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@16432db: 81 ms
```

**NOTE: I have utilized below jar files:**

- android,
- selenium-java-2.47.1
- java client2.2.0
- selenium-java-client-driver-1.0.1
- selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1
- selendroid-standalone-0.10.0-with-dependencies

Can some one help if i miss anything.
Thanks,

Comment: please share all code with test..

Answer (score 0):

You get classNotFoundException/NoSuchMethodError when there is version clash between jar files. 
Also looking at exception, it is giving error on AppiumDriver.

- selendroid-client-0.16.0.jar
- selendroid-standalone-0.16.0.-with-dependancies.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar or greater
- selenium-java-2.44.0
- Java-client-3.1.0 (1.0.1 is too old)

**Edit**

- httpclient-*.jar
- httocore-*.jar

Make sure you use latest and same versions for httpclient & httpcore.
Try to use latest versions of all jars to avoid mainly `NoSuchMethodError`

**Edit2 for element not found in given context**
You need to explicitly switch to webview so that appium can lookout element.
try getting all webviews as below:

```
String nr = driver.getWindowHandles().toString();
System.out.print(nr);
```

IT will return you an array similar to :

```
[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_1, WEBVIEW_0]
```

Now switch to WEBVIEW_1 as:

```
driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW_1");
```

Please note: Appium is not good in switching between multiple webviews.
(Atleast I faced that issue.)

Comment: I have updated jar with htmlclient and html core ..,

Comment: So, is it working.? This may be very basic to ask, but are you starting Appium server before running test cases?

Comment: Yes starting it ... before test cases, I see below error          java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Please provide complete stack trace. Edit your question with new stack trace. Avoid copying it in comments.

Comment: Yes it did, below is my updated script which uses very few jar files

Comment: Is your code communicating with Appium successfully.?? I can not see your updated script. Also list the jars you are using.

Comment: Jar files for latest java client 3.2.0 requires 1. commons-validator-1.4.1.jar,
2. java-client-3.2.0.jar
3. selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar

Comment: comments please find the below code    `AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService
  .buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
  .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:/Program Files/Appium/node.exe"))
  .withAppiumJS(new File("D:/Poornima/Selenium_Automation_req/Jar_files/APPIUM/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js"))
  .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723)
  .withLogFile(new File("D:/Poornima/Selenium_Automation_req/Jar_files/APPIUM/appiumlogs/logs.txt")));`

Comment: Continuing my script: `@Test
public void applogin() throws NoSuchElementException {WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));weusername.sendKeys("abc");@AfterClass public void appiumServiceStop(){if(service != null)service.stop();driver.quit();}`

Comment: `FAILED: applogin org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 114 milliseconds `

Comment: I am unable to locate the elements for one of my Hybrid app which uses web view, can someone suggest ways to locate the elements , i am using java to automate this phonegap app, Thanks,

Comment: can you please avoid pasting long stack trace / codes in comment? please follow link suggested by piet.t in below answer. Find my Edit2 for your error above.